# SYN-ACK with identical MACs

Tags: networking, linux-networking, arp

What could cause a CentOS machine to respond with SYN-ACK packet having both source and destination MACs set to the address of the NIC from which the packet is being sent?

Comment: Is it a virtual machine?

Comment: Yes, it is KVM.

Comment: Sounds like it's the KVM talking to the host.

Comment: There are two KVMs connected via bridge. No host connection on this interface.

Comment: Can you show us a packet capture of the handshake with the MACs and IPs? You can obscure the actual values if you want to hide your MACs and IPs, as long as we see the behaviour like you do.